# Using next() on generator function

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have this generator function:-

```
def gen():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i*i
```

Now when I am calling `next()` on `gen()`, it is giving the first element each time.

```
>>> next(gen())
0
>>> next(gen())
0
```

But when I use that in a `for` loop, it works as expected:

```
>>> for i in gen():
...     print(i)
... 
0
1
4
```

Can someone explain the cause of this effect and the concept that I am missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your function returns a new generator each time you call `gen()`.

I think the simplest way to understand is to contrast what you are doing:

```
>>> next(gen())
0
>>> next(gen())
0
```

with this:

```
>>> my_gen = gen()
>>> next(my_gen)
0
>>> next(my_gen)
1
>>> next(my_gen)
4
>>> next(my_gen)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

In this latter case, I am getting new values from the *same* generator.

Comment: >Your function returns a new generator each time you call gen().
Well, then a generator function is directly not a generator, not until it is initialised, but why?

Comment: @edam Think about it: it wouldn't be very useful if a generator function always returned the same generator. If you wanted to create a new generator, you'd have to write a new function. For reference, see the docs: [generator (function)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator): *"A function which returns a [generator iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator)."*

Answer (score 6):

Each time you call the function it returns a generator object. And each time you call the next on it you'll get the first item which is `0 * 0` because you're not calling the next on same object (each time a new one). But in second case you're looping over one generator object and it will continue to consuming the generator until it hit the `StopIteration`.

For a better demonstration you can create two iterator objects from your generator function and loop over them simultaneously:

```
In [17]: g = gen()

In [18]: k = gen()

In [19]: for i, j in zip(g, k):
    ...:     print(i, j)
    ...:     
0 0
1 1
4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
def gen(d):
    for i in d: 
        yield i 

obj = gen(days)

print(next(obj, 'Default Value')) # 'Sun'
print(next(obj, 'Default Value')) # 'Mon'

print('--------------------------')    

for j in obj:
    print(j)  # 'Tue' 'Wed' 'Thu' 'Fri' 'Sat'

 
print(next(obj, 'Default Value')) # Default Value
```

- In above we have already called next() two times so as we know generator function save the state of program execution so in for loop it returns the
  object from next generator object
- **But if first We use `for loop` then during the for loop we received or called all generated objects, so we do not have any generator object left so we will get Default value for the `next()` function calls**

output:

```
Sun
Mon
-------------------------
Tue
Wed
Thu
Fri
Sat
Default Value
```